# How do I change outgoing ip address for port 80 only

Tags: linux, routing

On my linux server I have multiple ip addresses  I can use

```
ip route change default via  $gateway dev eth1 src $ipaddress
```

to change my default outgoing ip. Can I do this for only one port 
All outgoing packets on port 80 will use IP2 
All other outgoing packets will use IP1

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85932/how-can-i-redirect-outbound-traffic-to-port-80-using-iptables-locally

Comment: You can use an iptables NAT rule as per above comment but it's cleaner imho to bind your web server (if that's what you are using) to the particular ip address IP2 (ie approach the issue as service-centric instead of adding firewall/routing rules on top).